# form validation with ajax and jsp doesn't work

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

i am trying to develop a username validation with jsp and ajax but an error apperar  like this

`POST ://localhost:8080/web_application/deneme.jsp`

Show error :  `405 (Method Not Allowed)`

this is my jsp page what is wrong here

```
<html>
<body>

    <form name="form" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> 

        <br>
        <input
            type="submit" name="register" value="Sign up">
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script
        src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#form").validate({
                rules : {
                    username : {

                        required:true,

                        remote : {
                            url : "deneme.jsp",
                            async : false,
                            type : "post",
                            data : {
                                username : function() {
                                    return $("#username").val()
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }
                },
                messages : {
                    username : {
                        required:"Require Field" ,remote:"already exist"
                    }
                }
            });
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using `HTML 5` then don't need extra validation, just add `required` in `input tag` where you want such a validation.

Comment: Seems like the issue is with your server side not client side can you post your Server side code? As the Error is Method not allowed i guess you have GET on your server side but you are calling using POST.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

`http` is missing in your javascript file link location.

use the following:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The value of src can be with or without ```http:```